# Null homotopic maps need not be homotopic

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $Y$ is a disconnected space.

Let $y_0, y_1$ belong to distinct path components of $Y$.

First, I want to know why such points will exist?

Now, let $X$ be any topological space and $f$ and $g$ be two constant functions such that $x \rightarrow y_0$ and $x \rightarrow y_1$ respectively.

Then how to show that $f$ and $g$ are not homotopic?

Comment: Concerning the first question, recall what "disconnected" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path $y_0 \rightarrow y_1$ is the same as a homotopy between the maps $x_0 \rightarrow y_0$ and $x_0  \rightarrow y_1$ since $I \times \{x_0 \} \approx I$. So if you have two maps $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ with the properties you mention you precompose them with any inclusion $i:\{x_0 \} \rightarrow X$ to get the contradiction. If $f \simeq g$ then $f \circ i \simeq g \circ i$ which would mean that there exists a path between $y_0$ and $y_1$.

Comment: Why can't a path exist between y0 and y1?

Comment: @Gitika Because you said in your post that $y_0$ and $y_1$ are in different path components of $Y$.

Comment: What I understand by path component is just that they are maximal path connected sets. Please give details.

Comment: Call $Y_0$ the path component of $y_0$ and $Y_1$ the path component of $y_1$. If there was a path between $y_0$ and $y_1$ neither $Y_1$ nor $Y_0$ would be a maximal path connected set since they would be missing $y_0$ and $y_1$ respectively.